# Compiling GWT 2.6.1 at Java 7 source level

Tags: java, gwt, ant

I've recently updated my GWT project to 2.6.1, and started to make use of Java 7 syntax since 2.6 now supports Java 7.

However, when I attempt to compile, I'm receiving compiler errors such as

`[ERROR] Line 42: '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7`

Full output

```
Compiling module com.Project
   Validating units:
      Ignored 85 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter'
      Rebinding com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter
         Checking rule <generate-with class='com.google.gwt.editor.rebind.SimpleBeanEditorDriverGenerator'/>
            [WARN] Detected warnings related to 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver'.   Are validation-api-<version>.jar and validation-api-<version>-sources.jar on the classpath?
            Specify -logLevel DEBUG to see all errors.
            [WARN] Unknown type 'com.google.gwt.editor.client.SimpleBeanEditorDriver' specified in deferred binding rule
   [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/workspace/Project/src/com/project/ProjectFile.java'
      [ERROR] Line 42: '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7
   [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/workspace/Project/src/com/project/AnotherProjectFile.java'
      [ERROR] Line 188: Cannot switch on a value of type String for source level below 1.7. Only convertible int values or enum variables are permitted
C:\workspace\Project\build.xml:51: Java returned: 1
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:111)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)
C:\workspace\Project\build.xml:51: Java returned: 1
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:111)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)
C:\workspace\Project\build.xml:51: Java returned: 1
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:111)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.start(Main.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.main(Main.java:268)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.ant.execution.AntMain2.main(AntMain2.java:30)
```

How do I specify the GWT compiler to target 1.7? I was under the impression that it would do that by default, but I guess not. I've attempted cleaning the project, including deleting the gwt-unitCache directory but to no avail.

Here is my Ant compile target.

```
<target name="compile" depends="prepare">
    <javac includeantruntime="false"
           debug="on"
           debuglevel="lines,vars,source"
           srcdir="${src.dir}"
           destdir="${build.dir}"
           source="7"
           target="7">
        <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="gwt-compile" depends="compile">
    <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
        <classpath>
            <!-- src dir is added to ensure the module.xml file(s) are on the classpath -->
            <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
            <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
            <path refid="project.classpath"/>
        </classpath>
        <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
        <arg value="-sourceLevel"/><arg value="7"/>
        <arg value="${gwt.module.name}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ. I can build and launch the application just fine through the IntelliJ run configuration, but I only get this error when I attempt to compile via my Ant build.xml targets posted.

Comment: May be your IDE pointing to JAVA 6. Just point it to Java 7 and follow the steps listed here [Executing Ant Target](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/executing-ant-target.html). It will also help you [Configuring Global, Project and Module SDKs](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html)

Comment: Try `<javac source="1.7" ...` Read more [Problem with compiling a gwt project with ant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235491/problem-with-compiling-a-gwt-project-with-ant?rq=1)

Comment: I do have IntelliJ pointing to Java 7 (thus why it's able to compile via the run configurations). I have this issue when attempting to compile through Ant (either within IntelliJ or at a regular command line). I can confirm that JAVA_HOME is pointing to Java 7 (`javac -version` returns Java 1.7), and adding `<javac source="1.7"` didn't help either.

Comment: Try `<property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.7"/>`

Comment: Maven can be used as well to fix that for you.

Comment: It will help you [Running Apache Ant - Environment Variables](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html) just set the **environment variable** `JAVACMD` that point to the full path of the Java 7 executable (.exe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, the solution ended up being a combination of zpon's and Thomas Broyer's answers.

Firstly, delete the `gwt-unitCache` directory.

Then, in the `javac` Ant task, explicitly specify the source level

```
<javac includeantruntime="false"
               debug="on"
               debuglevel="lines,vars,source"
               srcdir="${src.dir}"
               destdir="${build.dir}"
               source="7"
               target="7">
   <classpath refid="project.classpath"/>
</javac>
```

Also specify the source level to the GWT compiler

```
<java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
        <path refid="project.classpath"/>
    </classpath>
    <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
    <arg value="-sourceLevel"/><arg value="7"/>
    <arg value="${gwt.module.name}"/>
</java>
```

Answer (score 4):

The GWT Compiler (and SuperDevMode's CodeServer) has a `-sourceLevel` argument that you can use to specify the language level, similar to the `-source` argument of `javac`.

The default value of `-sourceLevel` depends on your current JVM, so it should default to Java 7 if you use a JDK 1.7.

It's a good practice to be explicit and pass `-sourceLevel 7` (or `1.7`) to GWT, anda `-source 7` (or `1.7`) to `javac` (use `source="7"` in your `<javac>` Ant task)

Comment: How do I "pass `-sourceLevel 7`" to the GWT compiler? I can't seem to find the appropriate Ant property.

Comment: `<arg value="-sourceLevel"/><arg value="7"/>`

Comment: I added that underneath `<arg value="${gwt.module.name}"/>` in my `gwt-compile` target, but it still didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: The GWT module name must come last in the list of arguments (see http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#DevGuideCompilerOptions). Putting them after should have made the task to error out; should I understand that the error you're seeing comes from another Ant task/target? Make sure you **also** put `source="7" target="7"` on your `<javac>` task. Maybe update your question with what you tried that didn't work, and possibly the full output from Ant and full build.xml (use pastebin or similar to share them)

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the changes I made to my compile targets, as well as the full output.

Answer (score 3):

We just spend two days hunting down a similar bug, which turned out to be caused by a partial compilation of the gwt code with a wrong version of java (1.6). This had left some data in `gwt-unitCache` which somehow forced the gwt compiler to keep expecting the code to be for 1.6 (thus the diamond-operator warning), even though the java version was change to 1.7. The problem was solved by deleting `gwt-unitCache`.

I know that OP stated that he already tried this and it did not solve his problem, but I wanted to mention it as it might help others with similar problems. Furthermore, this could also indicate that if OP is using other pre-compiled gwt code, this might influence which version of java the gwt compiler uses.

Comment: This resolved the issue! While I did delete `gwt-unitCache` originally, I didn't try deleting it after explicitly setting the source level targets in the Ant tasks as suggested by Thomas Broyer.